# MongoDB Partial Replication

Tags: replication, mongodb

I am using MongoDB 3.0.10 with 10 databases in it,

also has implemented 3 member replica Set for it,

the question is it possible to replicate only selected databases from Primary to Secondary? If yes, then How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically looking for filtered replication, and as of writing this answer (August 2016) it is not available as a feature in MongoDB.  The relevant feature request is [SERVER-1559](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1559) for tracking/voting purposes (it is currently unscheduled).

In terms of options, you can get close to what you describe with the [mongo-connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector) but that is not an officially supported tool.

Comment: Thank you for response, this saved my time searching for filtered replication for MongoDB.